# Downloading Raspbian OS

Tags: raspbian

I am doing my project on Raspberry Pi. so i need the OS but I am not
able to download the OS from the website. The OS which i downloaded 
is corrupt every time. so I ask you to please send me the link
from where I can download the Raspberry Pi OS. I have already tried to
download the OS from the website but the OS which is downloaded is
always corrupt.

Comment: Define "corrupt". Define "the"  website. There's a fair chance that multiple users have their own copies and they might me unworkable, but it's unlikely that the sources at raspberrypi.org are corrupt.

Comment: Check the steps here https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/noobs.md. This worked for me.

Comment: As KDM said above, this isn't a particularly good description of the problem.  It's very common for new users to not know how to properly write the image onto SD, so it's more likely in my mind that this is the case than a corrupt download.  Please enumerate the exact steps you performed, what you expected, and what you actually got.

Comment: As others have said this is too ambiguous.  It could be taken to mean because you haven't been able to install the OS properly you are blaming the downloaded image -- although in fact you have not provided *any reason* for why you believe the file is corrupt.  You also did not say where you tried to download it from it the first place, meaning it is impossible for anyone to recommend somewhere they know to be different.

Answer (score 1):

If your internet connection is unreliable, I recommend using a download manager like "Internet Download Manager" (free) so that connection breaks will not cut the download process.
Always check the SHA-1 code posted under the download link, with the final downloaded file using a hash calculator.

> example from Raspbian Jessie: 
>   **SHA-1: 64c7ed611929ea5178fbb69b5a5f29cc9cc7c157**